# Using push_back(std::move()) in unique_ptr vector

Tags: c++, c++17

Hello I've been studying c++ and came across about unique_ptr.
I want to put in a integers in this vector.
I used vector because I wanted to practice the iterators too...

```
auto integerArray = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int[]>>(10);
std::cout << "Created:" << sizeof(integerArray)/sizeof(int) << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i<10;i++) {
    int num = i * 10;
    integerArray.push_back((std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>)std::move(num)); //compile error here
}

std::cout << "Output : ";
for (auto const& i : integerArray) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

This is the error:

```
error C2664: 'void std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int [],std::default_delete<int []>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int [],std::default_delete<int []>>>>::push_back(const _Ty &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>>>' to 'const _Ty &'
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int [],std::default_delete<int []>>
        ]
note: Reason: cannot convert from 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>>>' to 'const _Ty'
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::unique_ptr<int [],std::default_delete<int []>>
        ]
note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
vector(633): note: see declaration of 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int [],std::default_delete<int []>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<int [],std::default_delete<int []>>>>::push_back'
```

and why the first cout output says 4 instead of 10? I expected 10 cause I made a vector container with 10 blocks that can contain integer.

Comment: `sizeof(integerArray)/sizeof(int)` - this is meaningless for a vector. Use `.size()`

Comment: integerArray isn't a vector of ints, it's a vector of unique_ptrs pointing to arrays of ints

Comment: okay I'll do it . But why it have no meaning in vector? cause it's not sequentially stacked up in a memory like arrays?

Comment: @Nakta_Na `std::vector` stores a dynamic number of elements, so it needs a quantity of storage that is not known at compile time. But `sizeof` has to be a compile-time constant, so it does not include storage for the elements. Storage for the elements is obtained from the free store so is not included in a `sizeof(std::vector<T>)`. That size only includes counters or pointers used to manage that memory.

Comment: std::vector, will manage memory for you (how cool is that!). .  std::unique_ptr denotes ownership, it will clearly communicate who will have to do the matching delete. You make unique_ptr<T> with std::make_unique and if you want some other code to do the delete for you you use std::move (transfer of ownership). Note after the move you can't use the pointer anymore yourself. (Then there is also shared_ptr, but that's another story). Summary : in modern C++ you will hardly see new/delete or "c" style arrays anymore  (except in internal library code). So try to write code without them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how `std::vector` works.  It manages its contents already, and `std::unique_ptr` is not appropriate in this circumstance.  You are also declaring pointers to `int` being the type in the `unique_ptr` as well.

If all you want is a container of integers, this is all that's necessary:

```cpp
auto integerVector = std::vector<int>(10); // filled with 10 default-init values, 0 for int
std::cout << "Created:" << integerVector.size() << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i<10;i++) {
    int num = i * 10;
    integerVector.push_back(num); // Adds it to the end, not just first "unfilled"
}

std::cout << "Output : ";
for (auto const& i : integerVector) {
    // Will print 20 times, as original 10 "0", and the
    // 10 you added to the end
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Be very careful with the names "array" and "vector" as they are not the same thing in c++.  They are similar, but not identical at all.

Comment: I'm glad this is helpful for you.  Please mark my answer as "accepted" if it is what you feel helped you answer your question.  And mark "up" on the rating next to it as well if you feel it deserves such.

Comment: Done the "accepted", but I need more reps to mark "up". I'll be active in this community and when I've got my reputation enough to do it, I'll do it first on your answer.

Comment: You're right.  I'll edit my response to be 100% accurate.  Thanks @AlanBirtles

Comment: I hope that's it.  Thanks for pointing it out @AlanBirtles.  Others might get annoyed, but I appreciate it.  I'd rather have it correct.